# How to generate 256-bit random number within a range on embedded system

Tags: random, cryptography, numbers, embedded

I need to generate cyptographically secure random number which is 256-bit long in specific range. I use microcontroller suited with random number generator (producer boasts that it's true random number, based on thermal noise). 
The upper limit of number to be generated is given as byte array. My question is: will it be secure, to get the random number byte by byte, and performing:

```
n[i] = rand[i] mod limit[i]
```

where n[i] is i'th byte of my number etc.

Comment: You should probably use *all* the bits provided by the hardware generator rather then specifically a single byte.

Comment: Note that if the upper limit of the raw random is not an even multiple of the upper limit you require, there will be a bias from taking the modulo.  To see this, imagine throwing a single die to generate a number 1 through 5 by taking the modulus of the number thrown.  You can easily see that a 1 or a 6 is congruent to 1 mod 5 where there is only a single die face for each of the other possible values.  So there is a 1/5 chance for each of 2, 3, 4, or 5, but a 2/5 chance of a 1 in this system.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this bias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard method, using all the bits from the RNG is:

```
number <- random()
while (number outside range)
  number <- random()
endwhile
return number
```

There are some tweaks possible if the required range is less than half the size of the RNG output, but I assume that is not the case here: it would reduce the output size by one or more bits.  Given that, then the `while` loop will normally only be entered once or twice if at all.

Comparing byte arrays is reasonably simple, and usually speedy providing you compare the most significant bytes first.  If the most significant bytes differ, then there is no need to compare less significant bytes at all.  We can tell that 7,###,###,### is larger than 5,###,###,### without knowing what digits the # stand for.

Comment: RNG gives me as many bytes as it wants. That is, there's a software library around hardware, which I must not avoid. The API makes me to pool the RNG for random bytes, I can't get as many as I want. Morevoer, I have to wait for and undefined time for bytes. But your solution may be good, thank you